# HTTP Error 404.15 not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I've seen a lot of different topics about this but none of the have solved my problem. I can't even reach my mvc site. I get this error before i even get to my loginpage. It seems that there is some problems with the cookies that it saves the cookies for to long but i have set it to not save the cookies at all now. I have changed the properties in my .csproj file that i found one topic about but i still have the same error. I have deleted all the cookies in this mapp "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies" in hope to delete the cookie that is to long but this didn't solve my problem.

I'm starting to think that maybe this have nothing to do with the cookies? Plz help![image]

Comment: It seems you are concatenating strings into your ReturnUrl variable (check where you are assigning the value to ReturnUrl). Can your clean the browser cache and then just hit the base URL without ReturnUrl.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your Account> Login action to see what's up. I've had this before, it's clearly a hard loop but I forget why. Simple debugging session will tell you.

Comment: Actually from memory maybe something silly like not having [AllowAnonymous] on Login action? Or else there might have been an entry in web.config that had something to do with it. Sorry to be so vague but I can't quite recall. It's not your cookies.... this is one of those "silly" ones. By web.config I dont mean as per the error screen, I mean as per login  redirect. Either way its a hard loop building the string, not a single request, which you will see when you set the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm starting to think that maybe this have nothing to do with the cookies?

That is correct, this has nothing to do with cookies. As per [MSDN](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits), 404.15 indicates the query string is longer than IIS is configured to accept.

As for why your query string is too long, I can only guess. But something in your application is adding too much information to the URL.

Comment: hm yeah i read that. At first it seemed to me that it adds the same querystring to the old one like if it was saved in a cookie and it just added the new one to the old. But since i never have had this problem before and i didn't change anything in the code it is very strange. Also if i start any other projects they get the same error.

Comment: It sounds like it could be a misconfigured rewrite rule at the server level. But you should really check all of the config files at the server level (web.config, machine.config. applicationHost.config, etc) against their default settings for anything weird. Make sure you check every .NET framework version and bitness, too. If that doesn't work, it might not hurt to try deleting the files in the ASP.NET temporary files for the pertinent applications.